# Which minimum set of jars-files are necessary to run connect Tomcat to Activemq?

Tags: java, tomcat, jms, activemq-classic

Is there a list of jar files that needs to be placed into Tomcat's lib folder to connect to an ActiveMQ instance? I successfully used TomEE plus to connect to an ActiveMQ server running on a different machine and I wonder what's the minimum libraries neccessary to do that.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ?

Comment: web console says: 5.11.1

Comment: In the activemq/lib directory, is there a file named `activemq-all-5.11.1.jar`?  That might have everything you need.

Comment: Actually I looked for that jar-file but it seems that this is no longer part of the download package. I've found reference to that jar in "ActiveMQ in Action" But I got that file using maven, there is an artifact called activemq-all. Let's see if that works...

Answer (score 0):

I think you downloaded activemq from somewhere else or got it from other repository. If you try this link:
http://activemq.apache.org/download.html

you will get the latest download. It will contain as mentioned above a activemq/lib directory containing a jar file activemq-all. This you can use to connect to Tomcat.

Cheers